# How to modify the id field in django-rest-framework-simplejwt?

Tags: django, django-serializer, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I have a custom token serializer:

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer

class TokenObtainPairWithoutPasswordSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password'].required = False

    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs.update({'password': ''})
        return super(TokenObtainPairWithoutPasswordSerializer, self).validate(attrs)
```

This worked but now I'd like to change the `id` -field of my User to be `userId` and after that I can't get tokens anymore because it is searching for a field `id`. There must be some pretty simple way to modify this?

Comment: What error are you actually getting? It looks like it uses username? https://github.com/jazzband/djangorestframework-simplejwt/blob/0b8f3c63cc084073ba0df6f7c3db80a923ee723b/rest_framework_simplejwt/serializers.py#L30

Comment: @getup8 This is the error I'm getting:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework_simplejwt/tokens.py", line 161, in for_user
user_id = getattr(user, api_settings.USER_ID_FIELD)
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: Did you set `USER_ID_FIELD = 'user_id'` in the settings for the app? https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#user-id-field

Comment: @getup8 That's it, thank you so much.